# Downloads stop at 99% in Google Chrome & Internet Explorer 8

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, internet-connection

I was using Internet Explorer 8 fine until yesterday and downloads also stopped at 99%.

I installed Google Chrome however but downloads also stops at 99% or at 1 second remaining and then after some time says that network failed.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Chrome has been really shoddy with downloading large files recently, but if you had the same problem with IE as well, then it is probably the server. You can try a download-manager like Ash suggested, but depending on the server, it may not be supported. Depending on what the file is, see if there is an alternative way to get the file instead of through a web site, for example FTP, P2P, etc.; you may even be able to resume what you have already downloaded to save bandwidth instead of downloading it yet again.

Comment: In addition, if you have a router, check your [Internet connection status](http://i.stack.imgur.com/79pPv.png), especially [if it’s wireless](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Dvc.png). Some routers can get saturated and lose the connection when transferring large files through HTTP. If you find the connection cutting out, try pausing the download in the *Downloads* page for *just a few second* every now and then to give the router a moment to catch up/rest. Also, your ISP may be throttling large downloads and causing the connection to break.

Comment: smells like a transparent proxy or firewall. Where are you? Check your IT dept or campus people. Transparent proxies can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying these things:

1. If `Windows Firewall` is on, Than turn the firewall off for few minutes and then try to download it again. If that solves the problem then add exceptions for your browsers in `Windows Firewall` and again turn your firewall on again.
2. Try any downloader application instead of default downloaders of your browsers. You can try a trial version of [Internet Download Manager](http://internetdownloadmanager.com) or [Orbit Downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/download.htm). And check if it downloads or not.
3. Try re-installing Internet Explorer and or Chrome. Also try using FireFox instead.
4. Last option, try to disable your anti-virus software before downloading to see what happens.

Comment: Exiting Antivirus Software and Firewall Software is never an option. Properly configuring them is the option. They might catch a suspicious file and analyze it. In that case they drop the connection before the download gets complete.

Comment: Sometimes, the anti virus produces this kind of problem. Because on 99%, it checks the file, according to my experience. You can also try to install the latest windows defender (or  how they call it now).

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround try this:

1. Find the temporary file - something like filename.part
2. make a copy of the filename.part
3. Rename the copy to the correct file name e.g. correctname.exe with the correct extension
4. See if you can open the file - this seems to work if the whole file was downloaded but it stalled at renaming the file (mostly at '0 secs left' with Chrome).